# Can applications written for windows 8 run on windows phone 8?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

As Microsoft said that windows 8 and windows phone 8 share the same code base. If I use visual studio 2012 RC write an application for windows 8. I want to know whether I can install and run the same application on windows phone 8?
If the answer is yes we can prepare ourselves for windows phone 8 SDK by learning Visual Studio 2012 RC for windows 8 today!

Answer (score 4):

Right now they haven't announced everything, so this is just my speculation.

I guess that you will **not** be able deploy the same app (xap file) to WP8 and Windows 8. This by design. Why? Because they are very different systems. Your beautiful, fast and awesome  Windows Phone app will suck on Windows 8. There is no silver bullet. It's the same for HTML. You have to create separate mobile version of the web app, otherwise nobody will use it.

Answer (score 3):

They share the same *kernel* and probably plenty of APIs. But that doesn't mean the runtime environment in which your applications run is the same. E.g. very different form factors make it necessary to adapt the app anyway. Since they never said that Windows Phone 8 has the same application programming model as Windows 8 you can at the moment safely expect *not* to be able to deploy the same app to both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

That being said, you probably can expect to share a lot of code between both systems, especially if you're using either C# or C++ (with native apps coming to WP8 too).

Comment: correct they share a big part of the Win RT.
However you will not be able to run exactly the same app on both, consider the different display sizes, an app built for a tablet (which can contain much more information on page than a phone) scaled down to phone size would make all of the images and text tiny/unreadable

Comment: Exactly, the real benefit is that WP8 supports C++ so that desktop programmers can at least move over very old and tested classes.

Answer (score 1):

Application compiled for WP8 won't just run on Windows 8, but you can share lot of code into common libraries.
There is a chapter in Windows Phone 8 SDK about targeting both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 development. Mostly is possible either by Portable Class Libraries, referencing common files both in W8 and WP8 projects or using Windows Runtime Components.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Comment: Note also that the XAML syntax is that of Silverlight, not of WinRT. Using libraries is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Many Application designed for wp8 work on windows8 also as The developer have also to decide whether it will work in both of then,usually windows8 has not enough graphic and motion control so some WP games do not run on windows8,, You can always see any app permission notice to understand whether it work on wp8 or not on other hand there were also some windows game that has as much graphics that WP could not run,,
Like if you want game like assassins creed it will run on both operating system(WP,window) but in different manner
So it's chooses by game properties that define cap package to run or not