# Porting Windows Phone 8 application to Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How much effort is required in order to port an application from Windows Phone 8 to Windows 8?

Ideally, I would like to develop ONE application which can be deployed to both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. That seems [unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609058/can-application-written-for-windows-8-run-on-windows-phone-8), so instead I want the next best thing:

An approach to developing a Windows Phone 8 application that will make it as easy as possible to port the application to Windows 8.

Perhaps I can avoid certain namespaces, put certain compile conditions around certain sections etc. - I am hoping someone has the insight to list the things necessary to make it completely painless to port a Windows Phone 8 application to Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of application you create for Windows Phone 8. Phone includes a very cut down version of WinRT with XAML which resembles Silverlight, not WinRT. It will be impossible to make one application and it run everywhere.

The best plan of action you can take is abstract as much as possible to portable class libraries. Plan on at least doing a major duplication of effort on your XAML code though because of the conflicting syntax

Comment: Thankyou Earlz. When you say 'portable class libraries', you mean these, right?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a extremely broad question. And without considering what type of application, what architecture, what external impediments (databases, services, etc.) are in question, it'll also be extremely difficult to answer the question, without just giving general advice, that you're probably already aware of.

Windows Phone 8 is still largely based on Silverlight, rather than WinRT, besides from a few key components, such as audio routing or file-system handling (when available on WP8).

Wanting to deploy a WP8 app directly on Win8 makes little sense either, as the applications are designed in much different ways, to support much different platforms. Controls like the WP8 Panorama doesn't have a equivilant in Win8, the WP8 LongListSelector you might want to tweak layout wise for the phone, but different layout wise for the desktop.

The only advice I would be able to give is to stick to strict MVVM, abstract all phone/tablet specific API calls away in services, and use XAML themes/templates/resource dictionaries as much as possible to abstract any UI configuration away as well.

If you do that, chances are, you'll be able to port your C#, C++ and XAML very easily. That is, assuming you're not writing a VoIP app, or anything that's phone specific ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I created the question because it does not seem to have been addressed in blogs or stackoverflow. If I understand you correctly, the main issue is with UI, assuming I don't use phone specific functions?

Comment: It's not been addressed in blogs, as the SDK is not public yet.

Comment: I figured there would be thousands of developers with access to the SDK reading StackOverflow :)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yep. I've been waiting for it to get publicly released so I can finally answer all these questions on SO without getting sued lol